# Part of TextView clickable with a link

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I have an app with lots of text that is in strings.xml. Parts of that text are hyperlinks that have to be clickable.

Now, when I insert that text into TextView from the layout file it works, but when I try to insert that same text into the same TextView with tv.settext(getStrings...) it won't work.

Here is the code:

strings.xml:

```
<string name="some_text">
For you to see the article, you need to click <a href='http://www.google.com'>this link</a>
\n\n
after that etc...
</string>
```

Activity:

```
TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.link_tv);
txt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
txt.setText(getString(R.string.some_text));
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/link_tv"
     android:textColor="@color/privacy_policy_link_text_color"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post your TextView Layout (XML) as well?

Comment: Also, this could just be the way you posted it, but you have your TextView defined as _txt_ but then you use _tv_ Just making sure you know :)

Comment: It's just the way I posted it, TextView is called differently in the project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check below point before testing

- Check your link starts with `http://` or `https://`
- Place your String in CDATA tag (like `<string name="some_text"><![CDATA[PLACE_YOUR_HTML_STRING_HERE]]></string>`)
- Check you have added internet Permission in your `manifest.xml` file `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
- then dynamically html text can be set using below code into textView

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.html_string), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
} else { 
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.html_string)));
}
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.ALL);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: for me the same code is working very well 
`txt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.some_text), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
        } else {
            txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.some_text)));
        }`
[screenshot](https://prnt.sc/n0j0c0)

Comment: did you set anything in the xml for the textview?

Comment: I have made an empty app with just one TextView to try it again and it is not working. I don't know why...

Comment: can you share your code that you recently test and device details on which you are testing

Comment: text = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            text.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.some_text), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
        } else {
            text.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.some_text)));
        }
        text.invalidate();

<string name="some_text">For you to see the article, you need to click <a href="http://www.google.com">THIS LINK</a>
        after that etc...
    </string>

Comment: try this, this should work`<string name="some_text"><![CDATA[For you to see the article, you need to click <a href="google.com">THIS LINK</a> after that etc...]]></string>`

Comment: It shows now as a link, but when I click it it just stays selected, it doesn't open web page.

Comment: are you testing on emulator? check whether it has any browser app install init

Comment: No, I am testing on Samsung J5 and Huawei P20lite. They have browsers

Comment: try this code after setting text into your textView `Linkify.addLinks(txt, Linkify.ALL);
txt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`

Comment: and add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` permission to your manifest as well

Comment: I get a warning when I click the link. It doesn't open a webpage.
Actvity was not found for intent, Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=google.com (has extras) }

Comment: Ok, it is working now. "http://" was missing in the string. Can you edit your answer please? I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: well done by the way its all your effort nothing i have done helpful for you but for learning purposes for other users i will edit my answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

u can try this

```
   fun setClickableText(view: TextView, firstSpan: String, secondSpan: String) {
    val context = view.context
    val builder = SpannableStringBuilder()
    val unClickableSpan = SpannableString(firstSpan)
    val span = SpannableString(" "+secondSpan)

    builder.append(unClickableSpan);
    val clickableSpan: ClickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(textView: View) {
           // ur action here
        }

        override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds)
            ds.isUnderlineText = true
            ds.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.ITALIC));
        }
    }
    builder.append(span);
    builder.setSpan(clickableSpan, firstSpan.length, firstSpan.length+secondSpan.length+1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

    view.setText(builder,TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
    view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());


}
```

Answer (score -2):

Make 2 text views in layout file one for static text and another for dynamic text and assign the dynamic text through textView.setText(dynamic text)..
Hope it Helps..